# How to prevent showing duplicate informations in the sequential time period

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I wrote a method (with WebMethod attribute) which give me list of books :

```
 public struct BOOK
    {

        public string BOOK_NAME;
        public string BOOK_DESC;          
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<BOOK> GetMyBooks()
    {


        string _connString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BookStore;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(_connString);
        _conn.Open();
        SqlCommand _com = new SqlCommand("select * from Book_TBL where IsActive='True' ", _conn);
        _com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter bookdataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_com);

        DataSet bookDS = new DataSet();
        bookdataAdapter.Fill(bookDS, "Book_TBL");
        List<BOOK> bookList = new List<BOOK>();

        BOOK book;
        foreach (DataRow dr in bookDS.Tables["Book_TBL"].Rows)
        {
            book = new BOOK();
            book.BOOK_NAME = dr["book_name"].ToString();
            book.BOOK_DESC = dr["book_desc"].ToString();

            bookList.Add(book);

        }
        return bookList;
    }
```

and i wrote a script that call the "GetMyBooks" method every 5 second and show it in a div tag by id:"pejiGrid" in my WebForm2.aspx :

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#go").click(function () {
             setInterval(function () {
                     $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "WebForm2.aspx/GetMyBooks",
                     data: '{}',
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (response) {
                         for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
                             $("#pejiGrid").append("<tr><td>" + response.d[i].BOOK_NAME + "</td><td>" + response.d[i].BOOK_DESC + "</td></tr>");
                         }
                     }, });
             }, 5000); 
         });

     });
```

but my method and script append duplicate information in my "#pejiGrid", i want to show this information only once, is there any way,which i can do it by script? if it is not possible, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in code is OK. You need just a small correction in your script. Replace the success function body with this code:

var htm = [];

for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
    htm.push("" + response.d[i].BOOK_NAME + "" + response.d[i].BOOK_DESC + "");
}

$("#pejiGrid").html(htm.join(''));

If I correctly understood the question the problem was in using the 'append' method of jQuery, which was appending all new data received from server. Instead of that you were needed to replace old data with new one. So you need to use the 'html' method to replace the content of div.

One more advice. It will be better to store methods like 'GetMyBooks()' in web services files, developed specially for that purpose.

Wish you all the best !

Comment: I got it, It separate each element in htm, from others.